I try to publish photo and video at the same post on Facebook page, using graph api
I try to publish photo and video at the same post on Facebook page, using graph api.
There is error:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 10,
"fbtrace_id": "Afb5tvXsF_pInAzWWIvHLoC"
}
}
I try to publish photo and video at the same post on Facebook page, using graph api.
screenshot

Looks like you're missing some of the permissions mentioned here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish
